# Hiding specific objects from SF data event settings in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, datasource

This is regarding the objects that are shown to users while they set up a data source for SF data events based journey.

As a default all objects available in the SF org connected are visible there (including objects that were not set up as synchronized DEs).
What we would like to acheive is to hide certain objects so users will not be able to see or choose them during the configuration of the journey's data source.

Are there any solution/workaround to achieve this?

Appreciate your help,

Barak

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the Sales Cloud objects to which the integration user has access. This needs to be configured within the org to which your Marketing Cloud is integrated.

This will however not only limit the objects available in entry event, but also in synchronised data sources. If you want to add more objects, the permissions in Sales Cloud will need to be updated.

Comment: Do you think there is an alternative way to acheive this without changing the premission of the integration user? Support told us this is not best practice so they wouldn't be able to troubleshoot issues in the future. Thanks

Comment: This is the only solution, as there are no options in SFMC to limit this access. And support is correct, customising permissions of integration user (which normally is System Administrator with full access) is not recommended. You can, however, restrict visibility of each “unwanted” object individually, without adjusting the user profile - using Object Permissions

Comment: Hi Lukas, we've checked this with our SF admin and it seems it isn't possible to disable user from seeing certain objects without changing its system administer profile. Or perhaps we misunderstood what you wrote. Can you please clarify this? Thanks again